# why does getElementByID return Nothing instead of NULL

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, null, getelementbyid

In VBA, if I use getElementByID("id_name") and the id does not exist the function returns nothing rather than null.  This leaves me not knowing if the DOM has yet to render the element or if the element truly does not exists.  It seems like the spec requires a NULL to be returned and NULL does not equal Nothing.  So my question is does this DOM function return NULL, Nothing or is it dependent upon something I'm missing?  Thanks

snipit

```
If Not IsNull(p_IE.Document.getElementById(MAIN_SR_CONTAINER)) Then
 ' If I do not receive NULL I want to assume that I can grab the element.
 ' Still, I verify that the element is not Nothing

 ' problem is that NULL <> Nothing so if the element does not exist my code loops for eternity
 ' I do look at the readystate of the p_IE object and wait till it = 4
 ' But the elements may be being created by embedded javascript on the fly

    Set elMainSRContainer = p_IE.Document.getElementById(MAIN_SR_CONTAINER)
    Do While elMainSRContainer Is Nothing
        Set elMainSRContainer = p_IE.Document.getElementById(MAIN_SR_CONTAINER)
    Loop

    :
    :
Else
    ' bail
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN documentation for getElementById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536437(v=vs.85).aspx) says that the method return value is type IHTMLElement.  This would be an `Object` type in VBA.  The documentation goes on to say that the method

> Returns the first object with the specified ID or null if there is no match.

My guess is that because, in VBA, `Objects` can't hold `Null` so the `Null` is being interpreted as `Nothing`.

I would try changing

```
If Not IsNull(p_IE.Document.getElementById(MAIN_SR_CONTAINER)) Then
```

to

```
If Not (p_IE.Document.getElementById(MAIN_SR_CONTAINER) Is Nothing Then
```

Answer (score 0):

All was OK. You just needed to put the ID name in quotation marks ""

So

```
If Not IsNull(p_IE.Document.getElementById("MAIN_SR_CONTAINER")) Then
```

Try it.